# How to set & validate cookie in Spring boot VueJS application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, vue.js

Backend is build on Spring boot and frontend is build using VueJS.

I'm setting a sample cookie from spring boot like

```
@PostMapping(path = "/login")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> loginUser(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse, @RequestBody final User user) {
    try {
        SessionResponse sessionResponse = loginService.authenticateUser(user);
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("token", sessionResponse.getToken());
        httpResponse.addCookie(cookie);
        return new ResponseEntity<SessionResponse>(sessionResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Failed with exception " + e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Using the below snippet to retrieve the cookies from request

```
@GetMapping(path = "/dashboard")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> dashboardData(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
    try {
        String cookies = getCookies(httpRequest);
        getLogger().info("dashboardData -> cookies :: " + cookies);
        // will get dashboard data
        return new ResponseEntity<>(dashboardResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Failed with exception " + e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}

private String getCookies(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
    Cookie[] cookies = httpRequest.getCookies();
    getLogger().info(cookies);
    if (cookies != null) {
        return Arrays.stream(cookies).map(c -> c.getName() + "=" + c.getValue()).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    }
    return null;
}
```

But I'm getting `null`

Comment: I'd simply try printing the cookies to check you're actually getting them :)

Comment: `Cookie[] cookies` is null

Comment: Try it with PostMan too? And what's the end point / url you're sending the response from?

Comment: Updated my code. I'm not able to see the cookies in postman as well

Comment: Then maybe you're not reaching the endpoint. Try check what you actually get, what status does it have, body etc?

Comment: I'm getting 200 status and the response. but in headers/cookies I dont see the value that I set

Comment: Could it be that you always return null in the getCookies method that you made yourself (private). private String getCookies(HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
    Cookie[] cookies = httpRequest.getCookies();
    getLogger().info(cookies);
    if (cookies != null) {
        return Arrays.stream(cookies).map(c -> c.getName() + "=" + c.getValue()).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    }
    return null;  <----
}

Comment: You attach cookies to httpResponse but you return sessionResponse. Shouldn't it be sessionResponse you attach cookies to?

Comment: I'm able to send headers `httpResponse.addHeader("token", "jhrghbhbvsdjhbhsdcsdfsd");` and see in Postman/VueJS

Comment: In what route? I'm talking about the /login , you return this: return new ResponseEntity<SessionResponse>(sessionResponse, HttpStatus.OK); but you add the cookie to    httpResponse.addCookie(cookie); <-- this one isn't returned

Comment: And for the other route, /dashboard you return, dashboardResponse. So wouldn't you need to add cookies to that, if you want it to have the cookies? I don't see where you get the dashboardResponse from but it seems like you're not adding cookies to it.